# consumir un servicio web vis API Rest con parametros xml de entrada

Tags: c#, rest

Tengo que consumir un servicio `REST` con `C#`, pero la verdad es que estoy un poco perdido en este tema.

por una parte, el servicio a consumir, requiere de varios parametros XML que tiene el siguiente formato

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<prescription>
<patient>
<allergies>
<allergy>vidal://allergy/1</allergy>
<allergy>vidal://allergy/2</allergy>
<allergy>vidal://allergy/3</allergy>
</allergies>
<molecules>
<molecule>vidal://molecule/1</molecule>
</molecules>
<pathologies>
<pathology></pathology>
</pathologies>
<breastFeeding>NONE</breastFeeding>
<creatin>120</creatin>
<dateOfBirth>2012-11-08T15: 44:50.980+01:00</dateOfBirth>
<gender>MALE</gender>
<height>180.0</height>
<hepaticInsufficiency>SEVERE</hepaticInsufficiency>
<weeksOfAmenorrhea>5</weeksOfAmenorrhea>
<weight>80.0</weight>
</patient>
<prescription-lines>
<prescription-line>
<drugId>1</drugId>
<drugType>COMMON_NAME_GROUP</drugType>
</prescription-line>
<prescription-line>
<drugId>2</drugId>
<drugType>COMMON_NAME_GROUP</drugType>
</prescription-line>
</prescription-lines>
</prescription>
```

Donde los datos necesarios, los obtengo desde un formulario.

Para realizar la llamada al servicio, tengo una funcion, en donde especifico la direccion base, que incorpora las credenciales necesarias para usar el servicio, ademas del metodo `POST` para la consulta.

Resultando de esta forma

```
http://api-cl.vidal.fr/rest/api/alerts?app_id=5e151413&
app_key=f80c77cbd1ef392f541ee83889d1d2d4 method='post' result=" + xmlFile;
```

Los parametros de entrada descriptos mas arriba, los transformo a `xml`, a traves de una funcion que le agrega los `tags` necesarios para cada dato.

Esta es la funcion que tengo para realizar a llamada.

```
        public string EjecutarConsulta2(string url)
    {
        string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Codigo Error : " + response.StatusCode);
            }

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return strResponseValue;

    }
```

Mi problema, es que no se donde van los parametros de entrada en formato `XML`.

Tienen que ir concatenados junto a la URL? 
**(hice esto, pero no funciono)**.

alguien sabe como se ejecutan estas consultas?
Saludos

Comment: Hola, el servicio a consumir REST es uno implementado por tí? O es uno de terceros? Si es de terceros deberías obtener la documentación del servicio y ver cómo se usa. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

a mi modo de ver si tienes que enviar un XML, éste debe enviarse en el `Body` de la petición.

```
public string EjecutarConsulta2(string url, string xmlToSend)
{
    string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
    request.ContentType = "application/xml"; // establecer el ContentType de la petición a XML
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlToSend);

    using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) // generar la petición mandando al Body el XML a enviar
    {
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Codigo Error : " + response.StatusCode);
            }

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return strResponseValue;
}
```